# Unable to open .mpproj files through vsmsbuild in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to open .mpproj files in visual studio using vsmsbuild. We are using VsMsBuild.Corext.3.2.15. When i run vsmsbuild command from command prompt for specific project,the below error is displayed:
[image]

After that, mpproj is shown as incompatible:
[image]

Please suggest on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

VS2019 IDE does not contain the MP project by default. The MP project is a vs extension that creates the project template.

For **VS2019**, you have to download and then install the [System Center Visual Studio Authoring Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30169) so that your VS2019 can recognize the **MP** project and then build it.

When you finish the installation, restart VS,  then reload your MP project and you will get what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have already installed System center visual studio authoring extension, able to open it in visual studio. Issue here is, i am unable to open it through vsmsbuild.exe by running vsmsbuild command in command prompt.

Comment: What is vsmsbuild.exe, could you please provide some info about it? Is `msbuild.exe`?

Comment: Where does `VsMsBuild.Corext.3.2.15` come from? In general, we always use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe xxx\xxx.mpproj -t:build`

Comment: msbuild works with command line whereas vsmsbuild works in visual studio. Since developers are used to visual studio, we need vsmsbuild to work. VsMsBuild.Corext.3.2.15 is coming from different location: D:\CxCache\VsMsBuild.Corext.3.2.15\v4.0.\VsMsBuild.exe

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I did know how to download VsMsBuild.Corext and use it. I did not search any info about it. Was it abandoned? Also, as my guess, `VsMsBuild.exe` of `VsMsBuild.Corext` is just a basic build framework tool and the extension `System Center Visual Studio Authoring Extensions` did not integrate mp info into `vsmsbuild.exe`. And I think that could not support build for mp projects.

Comment: Also, I think you want to get a build tool that could be installation without vs ide, a single lightweight command line build tool, right? If so, you could [download Build Tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019). It is a single build tool with vs environment and the extension could be integrated into the build tool. When I used it, I can build the mp projects. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Z5Z.png).